# Building a Handler to Log over SFTP

Tags: groovy

I'm attempting to build a Handler to perform a put operation with every logging event on a log file over Sftp.  Currently, I've built a new logger in line of my Groovy script that uses an SftpConnector artifact's ChannelSftp to perform a put and append to a log file.  When I run my code I receive an error message saying it's an Invalid Type=105.  If I append to a string and at the end of my script upload the strings contents to my log file then there are no issues.  I'm guessing that the error I'm receiving is due to multiple put operations on the same file in rapid secession?

```
def LOG = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME)
def handler = new Handler() {

///String outputBuffer
@Override
void publish(LogRecord record) {
    ProgressMonitor monitor = new ProgressMonitor()
    String aRecord = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss aaa").format(new Date()).toString() +  " " + record.level.toString() + ":" + " " + record.message.toString()
    def stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(aRecord,"UTF-8")
    connector.getChannelSftp().put(stream ,props.getProperty("sftp.log"),monitor,2)
    while(!monitor.isFinished()){
        //just pause until logging is done.
    }
    stream.close()
    //outputBuffer = outputBuffer + new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY hh:mm:ss aaa").format(new Date()).toString() +  " " + record.level.toString() + ":" + " " + record.message.toString() + "\n"
}

@Override
void flush() {

}

@Override
void close() throws SecurityException {

}

void push(){

connector.getChannelSftp().put(IOUtils.toInputStream(outputBuffer, "UTF-8"), 
props.getProperty("sftp.log"), 2)
    connector.getChannelSftp().put(IOUtils.toInputStream('\n'), 
 props.getProperty("sftp.log"),2)
}
}

//SftpHandler handler = new SftpHandler(props)
//def handler = new FileHandler(new 
File(props.getProperty("log.location")).absolutePath, true) //provides a writer for log file.
handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter()) //defines the logger file 
format. must be declared
LOG.addHandler(handler) //adding the handler.
```

Comment: why you are not closing sftp channel after getChannelSftp? why not to open channel once handler initialized and close it on handler.close() ?

Comment: because the channel is opened further up in the code block.  At various points in the coding process I'm dealing with various input and output streams across the same connection.  If I close the connection inside of the handler it can break the processing of those streams.

Comment: edit your question: provide your code, full stacktrace, specify at which line error occurred, then maybe someone will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

When attempting a put on the open ChannelSftp it works fine so long as the previous put operation has completed.  If there are multiple puts on the same channel over the same session the server will execute and lock the file.

The way to get around this is to open a new channel, execute the put, and close the channel after inside the custom handler.  Each put command is executed over a different session and will be queued if the file is locked rather than simply rejected.